# How to apply conditional CSS to an element and persist?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I want to apply a style to an element using angular or jquery, but if I change the view I lose my styles. Should I use $window and local.storage ? Or are there simple ways to do this ?

Comment: If you apply a style using angular / jquery, you apply it to the markup that is present. If you switch views, you have to apply it to the new markup. Am I misunderstanding your question, or does that help?

Comment: How about using a ng-class to style the element?

Comment: @Lucas yes...brain fail after hours of work...I think this will work just fine for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

In a model-view-controller architecture, view is just a representation of the current state of the model. What you are saying is changing the view without changing the model, which contradicts it.

You can store the change inside the model, and then store the model in a service. By this way when you switch view you can always refer to the model and switches the styles accordingly.

Comment: Exactly, I used a factory to save my var style in the browser s local storage